# How to control the position of QDialog?

Tags: qt, qtgui

Is there any easy way to open the Qt dialogs in the same position as they were the last time the application was open ?
*i.e.* preserve position of dialogs between application sessions ?

By *easy way* I mean not to have manually write the window position in file, and then read :)

Comment: you mean something like setGeometry on QWidget?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [QSettings](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qsettings.html) class to achieve this. It's an abstraction class that allow your applications to store its settings in order to retrieve them at next launch.

Save settings:

```
QSettings settings("ValueName",  "Value");
```

Read settings:

```
QString v = settings.value("ValueName");
```

Comment: There is even an example of how to do this in the Qt documentation, at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qsettings.html#restoring-the-state-of-a-gui-application

Comment: Yes it is on the same page that the QSettings class representation

Answer (score 3):

Use QSettings along with QWidget::restoreGeometry() and QWidget::saveGeometry().

Answer (score 2):

Better to save dialog->pos(), dialog->size(), dialog->isMaximized(), cause dialog->saveGeometry() doesn't maximize the window.

[QSettings](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qsettings.html) is the preffered way to save configuration